# extract sub folder contents without parent folder using 7zip in batch files

Tags: batch-file, extract, 7zip

I have one zip file in source path called crewing.zip, zip file structure is as follows:

crewing\Build\Areas

i just want to extract only the folders and files under Build, i dont want the parent folder Build to be in destination location

Source Folder path: \10.201.1.6\TempPath\CL1

Destination Folder path: D:\Client1\inetpub\wwwroot

Expected Result: D:\Client1\inetpub\wwwroot\crewing\Areas

in unzip format, below is the code which i tried in batch files

7za X \10.201.1.6\TempPath\CL1\crewing.zip -y -oD:\Client1\inetpub\wwwroot crewing\Build* -r

please help me now in destination parent folder build also obtained.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
7z x -y -oD:\GWClient\inetpub\wwwroot \10.201.1.6\MariApps\GW\crewing.zip crewing\Build\*
```

You'll have to remove the Build dir afterwards.

Comment: Concur.
Since I want to unpack 2 folders in an archive, I need to specify 2 folders, and then move the crewing\Build folder into my working folder. Looks like I have to call unzip once per folder to unpack and then move the folder myself.